# 407 Authentication error while checkout bitbucket branch from eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, bitbucket

I have installed eclipse Luna and i try to checkout existing branch from the bitbucket through eclipse(file->import->GIT->Projects from GIT). In the branch selection screen, i got the following error:

```
    !MESSAGE https://test@bitbucket.org/test/eclipse.git 407 Proxy Authentication Required
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://test@bitbucket.org/test/eclipse.git 407 Proxy Authentication Required
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

I have set proxy through window -> network connection -> manual option and added following code in eclipse ini:

```
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
-Dhttp.proxyHost=192.168.2.55
-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
-Dhttps.proxyHost=192.168.2.55
-Dhttps.proxyPort=3128
-DsocksProxyHost=
-DsocksProxyPort=
-Dhttp.proxyUser=proxy
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=proxyss4u
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf.retry=5
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.connectTimeout=15000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.readTimeout=1000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.retryAttempts=20
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.closeTimeout=1000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.connectTimeout=3000
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.readTimeout=1000
```

But still i got the 407 Proxy Authentication Required issue.

Kindly advice us.